# iOs Device motion not working on Background Mode and Suspended Mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I'm developing a location app, the main idea is to communicate the position of the cell phone the most consistently but trying to save cell phone energy, what I'm trying to do is to detect device motion with 'CMMotionActivityManager' and with this try to activate gps or not like the following code:

```
// Start Device Activity
    func startDeviceActivity() {
        NSLog("startDeviceActivity method")
        DebugNotification.sharedInstance().debugNotification("startDeviceActivity method")
        if(CMMotionActivityManager.isActivityAvailable()){
            NSLog("CMMotionActivityManager is Available")
            DebugNotification.sharedInstance().debugNotification("CMMotionActivityManager is Available")
            self.activityManager.startActivityUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: { (data: CMMotionActivity?) in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    NSLog("startActivityUpdatesToQueue")
                    DebugNotification.sharedInstance().debugNotification("startActivityUpdatesToQueue")
                    self.monitorDeviceActivity = true
                    if data!.confidence != CMMotionActivityConfidence.Low {
                        if data!.automotive || data!.cycling || data!.running || data!.walking {
                            // Here we cover walking, running, automotive and cycling
                            if !self.deviceMoving {
                                NSLog("Device MOVING: Automotive or Cycling or Running or Automotive")
                                // Debug Notification
                                DebugNotification.sharedInstance().debugNotification("Device MOVING: Automotive or Cycling or Running or Automotive")
                                self.deviceMoving = true
                                self.turnOnGPS()
                                self.timer.invalidate()
                            }
                        }else{
                            // Here we cover unknown y stationary
                            if self.deviceMoving {
                                NSLog("Device on Stationary Mode")
                                // Debug Notification
                                DebugNotification.sharedInstance().debugNotification("Device on Stationary Mode")
                                self.deviceMoving = false
                                self.turnOffGPS()
                                self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.timerSeconds, target: self, selector: #selector(self.sendOnePosition), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        NSLog("Confidence LOW")
                        DebugNotification.sharedInstance().debugNotification("Confidence LOW")
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

But my main problem is that these code works perfectly on foreground mode, the background and suspended mode is not working, also this code is inside a function that is called on the AppDelegate file:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
     self.locationManager.startDeviceActivity()
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
     self.locationManager.startDeviceActivity()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive( application: UIApplication) {
     self.locationManager.startDeviceActivity()
}
```

How do I enable the device motion process?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can get motion updates in the background, but motion events won't launch your app into the background from suspended state like location updates will.

Comment: @Paulw11 by in background, do you mean the few moments before app getting suspended?